# Atributing fields in arcmap and excel

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinates, fields-attributes, excel

How do I populate a field in ArcMap (and Excel) with only a specific part of another field's attributes? For example: I want to populate the LATDEG field with only the *degree part* of a latitudinal co-ordinate and not the entire value.

Answer (score 2):

you can return the floored value.

In ArcGIS (with Python parser in the field calculator)

```
int(floor(!yourfield!))
```

if you have a text field:

```
!yourfield!.split(".")[0] # split at the dot and take the first(=left) part
```

(in Excel: FLOOR ( number , 0) )

Comment: With Python, it is also possible to get the first or last X characters, and to split by any character (`space` or `"` or something else) and return what is before, after or inbetween that character.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I've updated my post for text field. Note that the number of character is unknown (1, 2 or 3 digits for longitude in degree), so taking the X first would not work.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a query which I should have asked before this: I am trying to export an excel table to a dbf in ArcMap but it returns an error each time I try; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: please post this comment as a question, with details about the error message and what you've tried so far. someone might have the answer.